# Symfony 2 - Zip Archive - Save Zip

Tags: php, zip

I have a problem with Symfony 2 and Zip Archives. 
When I close the zip (zip > closed ()) the file is not saved. I think that the problem comes because it is not possible to write in the files of symfony.

I tried to use my script except the project Symfony, that works perfectly. The ZIP is created in the root of the directory.

I specify that I am on Windows. I use Wamp Server with PHP 5.3.13, Apache 2.2.22 and MySQL 5.5.25.

Here is my script :

```
<?php  
$host = 'localhost';

$user = 'root';

$bdd = 'symfony';

mysql_connect($host, $user) or die("erreur de connexion au serveur");

mysql_select_db($bdd) or die("erreur de connexion a la base de donnees");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `symfony`.`testzip`";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $img = $row["question"];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `symfony`.`rallye`";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $node = array();
    $node["id"] = $row[0];
    $node["name"] = $row[1];
    $node["code"] = $row[2];
    $node["urlarchive"] = $row[3];

    $json[] = $node;
}
mysql_close();

$json = array();
$nom_file = "rallye.json";

$f = fopen($nom_file, "w+");

fputs($f, json_encode($json));

fclose($f);

$zip = new ZipArchive(); 
$zipName = 'archive.zip';
if($zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
    echo '&quot;Zip.zip&quot; ouvert<br/>';

    $zip->addFile('fichier.json');

    $zip->addFromString('img.jpeg', $img);

    $zip->close();
    echo 'Archive terminée<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'Impossible d&#039;ouvrir &quot;Zip.zip<br/>';
    echo 'retour au site';
}?>
```

The purpose is to create a zip containing a blob got back in my table and a json file created from another table.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your code is not Symfony2? What are you trying?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, to go faster, I have created a script php but it will then be adapted in symfony. Maybe it's the problem...

Answer (score 3):

As Stony said it, it seems to have nothing to do with Symfony2...

Check the php.net page (the user's notes) about `ZipArchive::close` to solve your issue :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php